How to allow client side abort signal pass through nginx ingress controller for SSE streaming event?
I have a backend python flask server and a frontend react.js web application. I have a web-stream API for which I use fetch on the client. I also want the ability for the client to terminate the connection. I am able to make it work locally. However, in production, the backend server is behind a nginx ingress controller. The client abort call is not getting propagated to the flask server, and the connection stays open for the server, which is not the desired behaviour.
I tried adding
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
      proxy_ignore_client_abort off;

to the ingress yaml file. Entire code below:
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: external-ingress
  namespace: staging
  annotations:
    cert-manager.io/acme-challenge-type: dns01
    cert-manager.io/acme-dns01-provider: route53
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: "letsencrypt"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/tls-acme: 'true'
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: 'true'
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
      proxy_ignore_client_abort off;
spec:
  rules:
  - host: app.personal.org
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: app-personal-org-api
            port:
              number: 5000
        path: /api
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
      - backend:
          service:
            name: app-personal-org-ui
            port:
              number: 80
        path: /
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - app.personal.org
    secretName: app-personal-org-tls

However, had no luck. The call stays alive even if terminated from frontend
In frontend, I am using
const controller = new AbortController()
const signal = controller.signal

and then passing this signal to the fetch call.
